# How to start live streaming on Mac using FFMPEG?

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, streaming, live

I am working on a **MAC OS X Lion 10.7.5**.

How to properly install FFMPEG?

What I did:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
brew install ffmpeg --with-fdk-aac --with-ffplay --with-freetype --with-frei0r --with-libass --with-libvo-aacenc --with-libvorbis --with-libvpx --with-opencore-amr --with-openjpeg --with-opus --with-rtmpdump --with-schroedinger --with-speex --with-theora --with-tools
```

and even (I think this should work, but it doesn't)

```
brew install ffmpeg
```

Nothing works...I can't list the inputs, I can't start the streaming from the USB camera, I can't do anything.

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -s 320x240 -i video="USB cam":audio="USB mic" -f oss -acodec libvorbis -vcodec libvpx -f webm http://localhost:1234/streaming
```

The errors I get look like this:

```
unknown input format 'video4linux'
```

and the same happens for alsa, openal, vfwcap etc.

So did anyone try live streaming with **FFMPEG** from **MAC**?
How to install FFMPEG so that is supports **video4linux2** or **v4l2** or any input format at all? How to **list the devices** (**USB** webcams or **integrated** webcams)?

Answer (score 12):

You can gain access to the webcam in Mac OS with avfoundation.

To list the available input devices use:

```
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -list_devices true -i ""
```

An example that records the first device in the list to a file:

```
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -i "0" out.mpg
```

Comment: I'm on Mac OSX 10.9.5, ffmpeg version 2.4.2 (installed through homebrew) and this worked like a charm.

Comment: Neither of these commands work for ffmpeg 2.5.3 on OS X 10.10. Any ideas?

Comment: Jared: It may depend on how you install ffmpeg.  There are a huge number of optional libraries.  I've been using the following Homebrew install:

brew install ffmpeg --with-fdk-aac --with-ffplay --with-freetype --with-frei0r --with-libass --with-libvo-aacenc --with-libvorbis --with-libvpx --with-opencore-amr --with-openjpeg --with-opus --with-rtmpdump --with-schroedinger --with-speex --with-theora --with-tools

Comment: Did you ever find the solution Jared?

Comment: @RichardMilewski brew doesn't seem to let you specify optional package libraries with options like that. I get: `Error: invalid option: --with-fdk-aac`